# Parent bg shows/ child doesn't fill 100% depending on zoom factor

Tags: html, css

*Sometimes* the background of my parent-div is showing, and it's driving me crazy.

Setup:
Container-div with 4x4 divs inside (lets call them "outer"; blue bg).
Each of the blue "outer"-divs contains another div ("inner"; green bg).

Why I want it that way:
The green is supposed to cover the blue, because eventually the green will disappear (via jQuery - click) and the blue will show (it will have a bg-image instead of just the blue bg).

Problem:
Even though I tried different approaches (see codepen below), *sometimes* the blue bg will show.

[screenshot of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLFv9.jpg)

The point is -sometimes-. If the browser is zoomed to a convenient zoomfactor, it will display exactly as intended: the green covers the blue 100%. If, however, the browser thinks it's an unconvenient zoomfactor, the blue bg shows through. It also varies depending on the browser. If you view the below codepen-example in firefox rather than chrome, opera or edge, you might not even see that error (I didn't test it in safari).

**Question:
How can I ensure that the green will *consistently* cover the blue, no matter the zoomfactor (or browser)?**

css:

```
<style>
    #outer-container {
        width: 600px;
        /* height: 600px; */
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: row wrap;
    }

    .outer-box {
        width: 150px;
        height: 150px;
        background-color: blue;
        border: 1px solid black;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .inner-box {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: green;
    }
</style>
```

html:

```
<div id="outer-container">
    <div class="outer-box" id="outer-box01">
        <div class="inner-box"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="outer-box" id="outer-box02">
        <div class="inner-box"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="outer-box" id="outer-box03">
        <div class="inner-box"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- there are 16 outer-divs in total (see codepen) -->
</div>
```

[codepen-link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PeMzYV)

Additional info:
If I open that codepen with firefox, it behaves as intended, not in chrome or edge. If I open my visual studio code with firefox, I get the same background-showing-display-glitch(?) (depending on the zoomfactor).

I tried floats, flexbox and grid (see codepen); I used height/width in pixels, height: 100%, stretch (flexbox); pos: rel on outer and pos: abs, top,right,bottom,left: 0 on inner; display: block won't help, because the div is a block-element already (just to be sure I assigned it manually anyways); I use box-sizing: border-box - and I'm running out of ideas.
Yes, when I assign the border to the inner-divs the outer-bg doesn't show; but it's the outer-divs that are supposed to have the border, because once the green get's clicked away the border must still be there.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround to achieve my goal by now (which was to not let the blue show through) by just putting another container-div on top of the first one.
**My original question**, though, **remains unanswered** with that solution.
But just in case anyone was trying something similar:

html:

```
<div id="outer-container">
    <div id="inner-container">
        <div class="inner"></div>
        <div class="inner"></div>
        <div class="inner"></div>
    <!-- 16 of those inner-divs here -->
    </div>
    <div class="bg"></div>
    <div class="bg"></div>
    <div class="bg"></div>
    <!-- 16 of those bg-divs here -->
</div>
```

css:

```
<style>
    * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    #outer-container {
        width: 600px;
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    #inner-container{
        /* width: 600px; */
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .bg, .inner{
        width: 150px;
        height: 150px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        float: left;
    }

    .bg{
        background-color: blue;
    }

    .inner{
        background-color: green;
    }
</style>
```

[codepen link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gzVEWE)

Answer (score 0):

I had a look at this and it's puzzling. My best guess at this point is that it's a browser quirk/bug. With HTML and CSS there are so many ways to achieve the same thing so your workaround isn't necessarily bad. I managed to make it behave by putting the border on the inner-box's instead of the outer.

The reason I think it may be a bug is that it isn't consistent, as you have noticed yourself. In Chrome it happens at zoom level 125% (on a standard 1080 screen). In FireFox it doesn't happen at all on any zoomlevels and Edge has it at various zoom levels.

It looks a bit like the outer div at some levels ends up extending half a pixel wider than it's supposed to but it's hard to be sure.