# Why does the child div *sometimes* not perfectly fill the parent div?

Tags: css

In the code below, I would prefer to never see any of the red background. But sometimes, in some browsers, and at some zoom levels, the red background gives the appearance of an inner 'border' along the bottom, and in some variations right, sides of the parent div.

The real-world situation I started from is of course more complicated, but this simple example illustrates the problem.

I've fiddled with CSS flex and grid, and many of the various settings which sound like they might address this problem, but I haven't found any reliable solution.

I can reproduce in Chrome on Mac and Windows, and on Edge on Windows. But I can't reproduce at all on Safari on Mac. I haven't tried on Firefox yet. Remember to experiment with many zoom levels. The problem is not reproducible at all zoom levels.

```css
.outer {
  background-color: red;
  border: solid 1px black;
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}

.inner {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">seeing</div>
  <div class="inner">red</div>
</div>
```

[View on CodePen](https://codepen.io/craigsumner/pen/qBdBZeg)

Comment: Trying to get your CSS pixel perfect when using browser zoom is a death march. You may want to offer a button that grows/shrinks the size of your page (font sizes, padding, etc) using CSS instead. Maybe consider using `rem` to make manually scaling your CSS easier?

Comment: Ideally, the children should fill the parent, regardless of zoom. That seems to be the crux of the question. Also see [Parent bg shows/ child doesn't fill 100% depending on zoom factor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50541152/parent-bg-shows-child-doesnt-fill-100-depending-on-zoom-factor/50554668#50554668) and [Rendering differences when zooming in/out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57000175/google-chrome-rendering-differences-when-zooming-in-out).

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/57000175/2687446

Comment: I suggest adding to the CSS: 
 * { box-sizing: border-box}
This will help with layout consistency.  In short it makes all tags compute relative to the Board.

Comment: @PhillipWilliams, thanks for that. My project already sets the box-sizing property globally, for the reasons you mentioned. I didn't include it here because it didn't have any impact on this example.

Comment: Thanks all for the references to similar questions. I failed to find the right search terms to find those myself before posting. I'm disappointed that none of those have any satisfying resolution.

Comment: Update: This is bothering me in part because in my project, this occurs at the default 100% zoom level. I was able to workaround this problem in my own project by adding an otherwise completely arbitrary `margin-top: 0.03em` to the equivalent of the `outer` class. 

That exact value doesn't help in this example. But you can see the impact if you set the zoom level to 125%, and then add `margin-top: 0.53em` to the `outer` class.